# OneDrive uploads deleted files

Tags: sync, onedrive, cloud, cloud-storage

I have a question regarding the manner OneDrive deal with clients who have been offline for a long time and i hope that there is someone who can explain the mecanics behind this issue.

The case is the following:

> *User "A" has a computer that has OneDrive Business sync client installed. There is synchronized x number of files and folders.  A is
>   offline for a period of 2 months and in the meantime some of the files
>   that have been synchronized to A's computer have been deleted in the
>   cloud.  After the two months, A turns on on his computer again and the
>   OneDrive client begins to synchronize.*
>
> *Now, a problem arises, the files that have been deleted in the cloud, while A was offline are now uploaded again by A's OneDrive client and
>   the files will be distributed to all other clients who had deleted the
>   files earlier.*

Is there any way to avoid this problem and ensure that OneDrive remembers better which files are supposed to be discarded in such a case.

Anyone?

Comment: The feature set of `OneDrive Business` and `OneDrive` are significantly different.  One uses Sharepoint one does not.  Your answer would depend on your Sharepoint configuration.

Comment: Sharepoint configuration will have an effect on OneDrive syncronization behavior?. I'm using SharePoint Online default configurations.

Comment: It could have an effect on how files are handled when they are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneDrive syncs based on what the folder & file contents are in the cloud and the desktop at the time the sync is performs. It makes a best effort based on the situation it faces. When OneDrive has a conflict, it errors on the side of caution. This is why it will add the file rather than delete it.

Ideally, there should be a revision log kept of file manipulations so the OneDrive client can apply the changes from the time it was last online. Unfortunately, OneDrive is not designed this way. All computers need to be online to cascade changes immediately or risk sync issues like this.